# I need help for REACT in windows

Tags: windows, meteor

Today i installed react in my pc with windows, i had to install chocolaley, i didnt like this, but no problem, i installed chocolaley. Now, when i want to create a app (in the powershell of windows) using the command `meteor install my_app` the Meteor is so slow, and the instalation dont finish, the message that show all the time is `meteor loading package standard-minified css` I need hellp, and now i cant use linux or OSX. I have to tried the solution but i cant now.

Answer (score 0):

Try npm cache clean --force to clear your npm cache then install meteor again